# Silverlight MVC Controller not being hit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

I am working in Silverlight using ASP.NET MVC. I have a number of pages that use the same methods to send Json strings to a controller which processes them and stores them within the database. The same code is used over and over again for different strings and it works fine. However one page in particular after using  UploadStringAsync will not hit the controller. I do not need to post code as I know it is fine, my question really is has anyone else come across this before?

Comment: Further information has now come to light. The problem is I have a '<' symbol in the Json string that is being uploaded through uploadstringasync. This symbol is important and needs to be there but is apparently stopping everything as part of a byte end character. Any ideas how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using httprequest instead of the webclient to facilitate the transfer of data. This way I can convert my data to a base64 and upload it all successfully.